# How can I retrieve Proxmox node notes?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualization, proxmox

I am using proxmoxer to manipulate machines on ProxMox (create, delete etc).
Every time I am creating a machine, I provide a description which is being written in ProxMox UI in section "Notes".

I am wondering how can I retrieve that information?

Best would be if it can be done with ProxMox, but if there is not a way to do it with that Python module, I will also be satisfied to do it with plain ProxMox API call.

Answer (score 0):

The description parameter is only a message to show in proxmox UI, and it's not related to any function

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/baseblack/Proxmoxia to get started, [I asked this very same question on the forum](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/how-to-export-all-vm-ids-name-and-notes.27596/) as I need to generate some reports from a legacy system with dozens of VMs (and descriptions).

Let me know if you still need this, perhaps we can collaborate on it.